# Loading a Magento attribute's actual value

Tags: php, magento, attributes, product, magento-1.9.1

**I need to read an attribute from all products in a magento store who have it (some may not have it due to different attribute set), do stuff with it (regex/replace etc) and then save the newly computed value in a different attribute of that same product.**

For example, load product A, recognise that it indeed has the attribute X. Load X's frontend value "9000", multiply that by 2 and save 18000 in product A's attribut Y.

After working my way through some posts here I have come up with this piece of code. It allows me to list the attribute ID (here manufacturer) of a couple of products in our store.

**Problem: This is only the manufacturers' IDs, not their actual names (I need the actual names). How do I get those. I found this snippet in another post:**

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getEntityId());
$product->setData('add_ten_pence', 1)->getResource()->saveAttribute($product, 'add_ten_pence');
```

**Basically I need the "getData-version" of that. The following line didn't work for some reason.**

```
$value = $product->getAttributeText($attribute_code);
```

**Any input on that matter is greatly appreciated. The attribute values I am looking for are of frontend type "dropdown" if that changes anything.**

My code so far:

```
umask(0);
Mage::app('default');
Mage::app ()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);
$productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();

$i = 0;
$storeId = 1;

foreach($productCollection as $_product) 
{
    echo "Updating SKU:".$_product->getSku()."\tID:".$_product->getEntityId()." ";
    $manufacturer = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product')->getAttributeRawValue($_product->getEntityId(), 'manufacturer', $storeId);
    echo "\tManufacturer: ".$manufacturer."<br>";

    $i++; //(DEBUG break loop early to reduce loading time)
    if($i>10) break;
}
?>
```

Comment: The part about `$product->getAttributeText(...)` should work, it usually does so quite reliably.  Remember that the current store is set to "admin" so those option labels will be used, not any of the front stores.  Double check that `$attribute_code` is correct.

Comment: Thanks. I looked into getAttributeText once more and got it to work. I am currently making progress and will post my code here. Should I edit my question once I got it solved or should I post it as an answer?

Comment: If it's solved then it's an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try it, because collection not select specific attribute, and check in admin if it attribute has property filter in collection,

```
$product=Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($id);

$product->getData($attribute_code);
```